# JS HTML CSS: Having trouble with calling popOpen() inside my parameters

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm current having trouble with my code. I'm trying to call my openPop() function with the input of 'pop' inside some of my sensor code and nothing pops up, even though I think I'm calling up my popup. I was wondering if anyone could help me.
Here is my code:

```js
// calling the dice id and "listening" to when it is clicked and then running numChange
var dice = document.getElementById("dice").addEventListener("click", numChange);
// creating a function called numChange without any arguments and alerting a random number 1-6
function numChange() {
  alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
}
// slecting "man" using doc.qs and calling upon ".man"
let circle = document.getElementById("stick-man");
let moveBy = 25;
//adding a el to window and setting atrubute to "load", as well a empty () and a reference =>
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  //circle position now "absolute"
  circle.style.position = "absolute";
  //my circle is now at the top left corner
  circle.style.left = 0;
  circle.style.top = 0;
});

function verifyPosition (circleLeftPosition,circleRightPosition, moveBy ){
  console.log(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition );
  if(circleLeftPosition =='550px' && circleRightPosition=='75px'){
       
      //Something.. HAVE NO IDEA WHAT THOUGH!
    }
}
// another ael but this time for "keyup", with e inside our (), and our => {}
window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
      //fist case checs for left arrow
    case "ArrowLeft":
      verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy);
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
      //second for right arrow
    case "ArrowRight":
      verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy);
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      //third for up
      verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy);
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      //fourth for down
      verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy);
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
  }
});

const popOpen = document.querySelectorAll('[data-popup-target]');
const popClose = document.querySelectorAll('[data-button]');
const overLay = document.getElementById('overlay');

popOpen.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop = document.querySelectorAll(button.dataset.popupTarget);
    openPopup(pop);
  });
});

popClose.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop = button.closest('.popup');
    closePopup(pop);
  });
});

function openPopup(pop) {
  if (pop == null) return;
  popup.classList.add('active');
  overLay.classList.add('active');
}

function closePopup(pop) {
  if (pop == null) return;
  popup.classList.remove('active');
  overLay.classList.remove('active');
}


const openErrorPop = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]')
const closeErrorPop = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pop-close]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('pop-idOverlay')

closeErrorPop.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop = button.closest('.class-pop')
    closePop(pop)
  })
})

openErrorPop.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop = document.querySelector(button.dataset.target)
    openPop(pop)
  })
})

function openPop(pop) {
  if (pop == null) return
  pop.classList.add('active')
  overlay.classList.add('active')
}

function closePop(pop) {
  if (pop == null) return
  pop.classList.remove('active')
  overlay.classList.remove('active')
}

const openErrorPop2 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target2]')
const closeErrorPop2 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pop-close2]')
const overlay2 = document.getElementById('pop-idOverlay2')

closeErrorPop2.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop2 = button.closest('.class-pop2')
    closePop2(pop2)
  })
})

openErrorPop2.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop2 = document.querySelector(button.dataset.target2)
    openPop2(pop2)
  })
})

function openPop2(pop2) {
  if (pop2 == null) return
  pop2.classList.add('active')
  overlay2.classList.add('active')
}

function closePop2(pop2) {
  if (pop2 == null) return
  pop2.classList.remove('active')
  overlay2.classList.remove('active')
}


const openErrorPop3 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target3]')
const closeErrorPop3 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pop-close3]')
const overlay3 = document.getElementById('pop-idOverlay3')

closeErrorPop3.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop3 = button.closest('.class-pop3')
    closePop3(pop3)
  })
})

openErrorPop3.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop3 = document.querySelector(button.dataset.target3)
    openPop3(pop3)
  })
})

function openPop3(pop3) {
  if (pop3 == null) return
  pop3.classList.add('active')
  overlay3.classList.add('active')
}

function closePop3(pop3) {
  if (pop3 == null) return
  pop3.classList.remove('active')
  overlay3.classList.remove('active')
}

const openErrorPop4 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target4]')
const closeErrorPop4 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pop-close4]')
const overlay4 = document.getElementById('pop-idOverlay4')

closeErrorPop4.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop4 = button.closest('.class-pop4')
    closePop4(pop4)
  })
})

openErrorPop4.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop4 = document.querySelector(button.dataset.target4)
    openPop4(pop4)
  })
})

function openPop4(pop4) {
  if (pop4 == null) return
  pop4.classList.add('active')
  overlay4.classList.add('active')
}

function closePop4(pop4) {
  if (pop4 == null) return
  pop4.classList.remove('active')
  overlay4.classList.remove('active')
}

const openErrorPop5 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target5]')
const closeErrorPop5 = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pop-close5]')
const overlay5 = document.getElementById('pop-idOverlay5')

closeErrorPop5.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop5 = button.closest('.class-pop5')
    closePop5(pop5)
  })
})

openErrorPop5.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop5 = document.querySelector(button.dataset.target5)
    openPop5(pop5)
  })
})

function openPop5(pop5) {
  if (pop5 == null) return
  pop5.classList.add('active')
  overlay5.classList.add('active')
}

function closePop5(pop5) {
  if (pop5 == null) return
  pop5.classList.remove('active')
  overlay5.classList.remove('active')
}

const btn1 = document.querySelector('#check');
btn1.onclick = function () {
            const rbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="check"]');
            let selectedValue;
            for (const rb of rbs) {
                if (rb.checked) {
                    selectedValue = rb.value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            alert(selectedValue);
            // if (selectedValue == "correct") {
            //   closeErrorPop3.forEach(button => {
            //   button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            //     const pop3 = button.closest('.class-pop3')
            //     closePop3(pop3)
//   })
// })
// }
};


// function random_item(items)
// {
  
// return items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
     
// }

// var block2 = '<button class="open" data-target2="#id-pop">'+
//     'I'+
//   '</button>'+
// <!--     popup head parent -->
//   '<div class="class-pop" id="id-pop">'+
// <!--     popup head -->
//     '<div class="pop-classhead" id="pop-idHead">'+
//       '<div class="classhead-title" data-id-Head-title2>Info Card #2</div>'+
//       '<button data-pop-close class="classhead-close" id="idHead-close">&times;</button>'+
//     '</div>'+
// <!--     popup body -->
//     '<div class="pop-classbody" data-pop-idBody>'+
//        'The internet was created Jan 1st, 1983 by two sophmores. For more information, visit <a'+
// 'href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet">This wikipedia page</a><br>'+
// <!--       form elment for checkbox -->
//       '<form>Did you click the link?'+
//         '<inb put type="checkbox2">'+
//       '</form>'+
//     '</div>'+
//   '</div>'+
// <!--     gray overylay -->
//   '<div class="pop-classoverlay" id="pop-idOverlay"></div>'

// var block1 = '<button class="open" data-target="#id-pop">'+
//     'I'+
//   '</button>'+
// <!--     popup head parent -->
//   '<div class="class-pop2" id="id-pop2">'+
// <!--     popup head -->
//     '<div class="pop-classhead2" id="pop-idHead2">'+
//       '<div class="classhead-title2" data-id-Head-title2>Info Card #2</div>'+
//       '<button data-pop-close2 class="classhead-close2" id="idHead-close2">&times;</button>'+
//     '</div>'+
// <!--     popup body -->
//     '<div class="pop-classbody2" data-pop-idBody2>'+
//        'The internet was created Jan 1st, 1983 by two sophmores. For more information, visit <a'+
// 'href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet">This wikipedia page</a><br>'+
// <!--       form elment for checkbox -->
//       '<form>Did you click the link?'+
//         '<inb put type="checkbox2">'+
//       '</form>'+
//     '</div>'+
//   '</div>'+
// <!--     gray overylay -->
//   '<div class="pop-classoverlay2" id="pop-idOverlay2"></div>'


// var items = [block1, block2];
//   alert(random_item(items));
```

```html
!-- title -->
<h1 class="board">STORIE</h1>
<!-- starting div's -->
<div class="stick-man" id="stick-man">/.  ./ </div>
<div class="dice" id="dice"></div>
<div class="inside-board"></div>
<!-- baord element -->
<div class="board">
<!--   start square -->
  <div class="square">START
<!--     opening button -->
  <button class="open2" data-target2="#id-pop2">
    I
  </button>
<!--     popup head parent -->
  <div class="class-pop2" id="id-pop2">
<!--     popup head -->
    <div class="pop-classhead2" id="pop-idHead2">
      <div class="classhead-title2" data-id-Head-title2>Info Card #2</div>
      <button data-pop-close2 class="classhead-close2" id="idHead-close2">&times;</button>
    </div>
<!--     popup body -->
    <div class="pop-classbody2" data-pop-idBody2>
       The internet was created Jan 1st, 1983 by two sophmores. For more information, visit <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet">This wikipedia page</a><br>
<!--       form elment for checkbox -->
      <form>Did you click the link?
        <inb put type="checkbox2">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--     gray overylay -->
  <div class="pop-classoverlay2" id="pop-idOverlay2"></div>

</div>
<!--   inactive sqaures -->
  <!--   garduin sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">guardian</div>
  <!--   blank square parent div -->
<div class="square">blank
    <!--     opening button -->
  <button class="open" data-target="#id-pop">
    I
  </button>
<!--     popup head parent -->
  <div class="class-pop" id="id-pop">
<!--     popup head -->
    <div class="pop-classhead" id="pop-idHead">
      <div class="classhead-title" data-id-Head-title>Info Card #1</div>
      <button data-pop-close class="classhead-close" id="idHead-close">&times;</button>
    </div>
<!--     popup body -->
    <div class="pop-classbody" data-pop-idBody>
      Bob Khan and Vint Cerf created internet in the 1900's. Eventually, the internet, then called the E-ternet became public. For more information, visite <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet">This wikipedia page</a><br>
<!--       form elment for checkbox -->
      <form>Did you click the link?
        <inb put type="checkbox">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--     gray overylay -->
  <div class="pop-classoverlay" id="pop-idOverlay"></div>
    </div>
  <!--   garduin sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">LAVA</div>
  <!--    LAVA sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">NATIVE</div>
  <!--   NATIVE blank parent div -->
<div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">blank
  <!--     opening button -->
  <button class="open3" data-target3="#id-pop3">
    Q
  </button>
<!--     popup head parent -->
  <div class="class-pop3" id="id-pop3">
<!--     popup head -->
    <div class="pop-classhead3" id="pop-idHead3">
      <div class="classhead-title3" data-id-Head-title3>Question #1</div>
      <button data-pop-close3 class="classhead-close3" id="idHead-close3">&times;</button>
    </div>
<!--     popup body -->
    <div class="pop-classbody3" data-pop-idBody3>
       Who created the internet?<br>
<!--       form elment for checkbox -->
      <form>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Vint Cerf<br>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Bob Kahn<br>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="correct">Both Vint Cerf and Bob Kahn<br>
      </form>
      <button id="check">Check</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--     gray overylay -->
  <div class="pop-classoverlay3" id="pop-idOverlay3"></div>
  </div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">wizard</div>
  <!--   wizard sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">blank
  <!--     opening button -->
  <button class="open3" data-target3="#id-pop3">
    Q
  </button>
<!--     popup head parent -->
  <div class="class-pop3" id="id-pop3">
<!--     popup head -->
    <div class="pop-classhead3" id="pop-idHead3">
      <div class="classhead-title3" data-id-Head-title3>Question #1</div>
      <button data-pop-close3 class="classhead-close3" id="idHead-close3">&times;</button>
    </div>
<!--     popup body -->
    <div class="pop-classbody3" data-pop-idBody3>
       Who created the internet?<br>
<!--       form elment for checkbox -->
      <form>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Vint Cerf<br>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Bob Kahn<br>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="correct">Both Vint Cerf and Bob Kahn<br>
      </form>
      <button id="check">Check</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--     gray overylay -->
  <div class="pop-classoverlay3" id="pop-idOverlay3"></div>
  </div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">king</div>
  <!--   king sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">bank
  <!--     opening button -->
  <button class="open5" data-target5="#id-pop5">
    Q
  </button>
<!--     popup head parent -->
  <div class="class-pop5" id="id-pop5">
<!--     popup head -->
    <div class="pop-classhead5" id="pop-idHead5">
      <div class="classhead-title5" data-id-Head-title4>Question #3</div>
      <button data-pop-close5 class="classhead-close5" id="idHead-close5">&times;</button>
    </div>
<!--     popup body -->
    <div class="pop-classbody5" data-pop-idBody5>
       Who created the internet?<br>
<!--       form elment for checkbox -->
      <form>
        <input id="check5" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Vint Cerf<br>
        <input id="check5" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Bob Kahn<br>
        <input id="check5" name="check" type="radio" value="correct">Both Vint Cerf and Bob Kahn<br>
      </form>
      <button id="check5">Check</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--     gray overylay -->
  <div class="pop-classoverlay5" id="pop-idOverlay5"></div>
  </div>
  <!--   bank sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">EARTH</div>
  <!--   EARTH sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">guardian</div>
  <!--   garduin sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">blank
  <!--     opening button -->
  <button class="open3" data-target3="#id-pop3">
    Q
  </button>
<!--     popup head parent -->
  <div class="class-pop3" id="id-pop3">
<!--     popup head -->
    <div class="pop-classhead3" id="pop-idHead3">
      <div class="classhead-title3" data-id-Head-title3>Question #1</div>
      <button data-pop-close3 class="classhead-close3" id="idHead-close3">&times;</button>
    </div>
<!--     popup body -->
    <div class="pop-classbody3" data-pop-idBody3>
       Who created the internet?<br>
<!--       form elment for checkbox -->
      <form>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Vint Cerf<br>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Bob Kahn<br>
        <input id="check2" name="check" type="radio" value="correct">Both Vint Cerf and Bob Kahn<br>
      </form>
      <button id="check">Check</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--     gray overylay -->
  <div class="pop-classoverlay3" id="pop-idOverlay3"></div>
  </div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
<div class="square">blank
  <!--     opening button -->
  <button class="open4" data-target4="#id-pop4">
    Q
  </button>
<!--     popup head parent -->
  <div class="class-pop4" id="id-pop4">
<!--     popup head -->
    <div class="pop-classhead4" id="pop-idHead4">
      <div class="classhead-title4" data-id-Head-title4>Question #2</div>
      <button data-pop-close4 class="classhead-close4" id="idHead-close4">&times;</button>
    </div>
<!--     popup body -->
    <div class="pop-classbody4" data-pop-idBody4>
       Who created the internet?<br>
<!--       form elment for checkbox -->
      <form>
        <input id="check4" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Vint Cerf<br>
        <input id="check4" name="check" type="radio" value="incorrect">Bob Kahn<br>
        <input id="check4" name="check" type="radio" value="correct">Both Vint Cerf and Bob Kahn<br>
      </form>
      <button id="check4">Check</button>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--     gray overylay -->
  <div class="pop-classoverlay4" id="pop-idOverlay4"></div>
  </div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
</div>
<!-- code for later -->
<!--   <div class="q1" id="q1">
    <ul>
      <li>Who created the internet?</li>
      <li><a heref="#">Bob Khan</a></li>
      <li><a heref="#">Vint Cerf</a></li>
      <li><a heref="#">Both Bob Khan and Vint Cerf</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  </div> -->
  
<!--   <table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table> -->
```

Here is the link because I can't put in all my code: [My Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dims09/pen/qBqLbez?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Okay....
I'm answering myself here because I figured to out. You can still post though, share your knowledge!
I simply made another modal and references back to it. 
I used getElementById, classList.add(''), and opacity: 1, 0; to make an opacity of 1 whenever active was added to a list.
Here is a snippet of the code I used for the function:

```
function openPosition () {
  popControl.classList.add('active')
  popHeader.classList.add('active')
  popButton.classList.add('active')
  popTitle.classList.add('active')
  popBody.classList.add('active')
}

function closePosition () {
  popControl.classList.remove('active')
  popHeader.classList.remove('active')
  popButton.classList.remove('active')
  popTitle.classList.remove('active')
  popBody.classList.remove('active')
}

popButton.addEventListener('click', closePosition);

openPosition();
```

Check out this link:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dims09/pen/qBqLbez?editors=0010)
for full details